# Two Tables, Overlapping Borders

Tags: html, css, border, overlap

Alright, so I have two tables set up, one outside the other.  In order to make it display properly, I had to put the inner table within  tags.  Problem is, I want the inner table to completely overlap the outer table's borders on the top, left, and right.  Here, look at this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/26Fnm/15/

html:

```
<body>
    <table class="main-body round">
    <tr><td class="nopad">
        <table class="header round">
            <tr>
                <td class="header">Test Text 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="header2">This is a longer test text two.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Line 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body table.round
{
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:25px;
}

.main-body td.header
{
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:50px;
    color:white;
    font-size:50px;
}

.main-body td.header2
{
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:30px;
    color:white;
    font-size:30px;
}

.nopad
{
    border-spacing: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

table.header
{
    background-color:#151515;
    width:100%;
}

.main-body
{
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    color: #202020;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #d2ffdc;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #101010;
}

#navi
{

}
```

You can see, in the upper left and right corners, a bit of the green coming out between the two tables' borders.  Not only do I want that to be gone, I want those two borders, on the top, left, and right, to essentially be one border, they are so overlapped.  Like if I were to copy paste those two tables on top of each other, and they were exactly the same width.  I've tried border-spacing, I've tried no padding, no margin, changing the size of the borders.  Nothing has brought me close to where I want to be.

Is this even possible?  Or do I have to settle for the appearance of overlapping with the inner table not having a border?

On a side note, why the heck does a JSFiddle link need code accompanying it?  The code is there on the JSF page!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26Fnm/17/)

```
table, tr, td{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.header2
{
    background-color:#151515;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
```

Comment: This is definitely about the closest I've gotten.  I could probably make this work, but it wasn't exactly what I was going for.  The only change to this, though, would be to have the border on header2 visible again, on TOP of the the border for main-body.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nopad {
    border-spacing: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
}
```